# Java async save/update data into db using spring

Tags: java, database, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I would to perform asynchronous save and update of data using spring4/boot1.5 and java8. How can I do this and is it possible to make it using @Async annotation on the method?

I have a controller which creating some data in external portal and I'am saving(later updating, after each creation) the status(logs) of whole transaction in the database (id + status - my columns in db). I want to return immediately id of this transaction to user and make this updating/saving of data in database in the background. How can I make it, could someone please provide me a snippet of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general yes, you can place an `@Async` annotation on the service's public method that should have a `void` return type (or alternatively it can return a future of result) and if the feature is enabled, spring will run the method in a separate thread when called from the controller. You can even customize the thread pool that will actually run the asynchronous code. And of course, it will return immediately so its asynchronous indeed for that matter.

You can read about the actual examples of `Async` for instance, [enter link description here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)